# Pros and cons of having static repositories in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, c#-4.0, repository-pattern

What are the pros and cons of using static repositories in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Wouldn't it be better to have all the methods available all the time -> means that the class get's instantiated only once instead of having multiple controllers referencing to the same repository class and its methods?

Or do I get something wrong here?

All help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pros:

- Repository is accessible everywhere

Cons:

- Repositories don't implement a contract which leads to a strong coupling between consumers of the repository and the implementation
- Impossible to unit test
- Might run into threading issues

Remark: Instantiating the repository on every request shouldn't be regarded as a performance issue.